# /etc/hosts ignored by Hadoop

Tags: java, linux, ubuntu, hadoop, dns

I'm setting up the namenode for Hadoop on a machine `node1.homer`.

The content of `/etc/hosts` contains:

`10.0.0.2 node1.homer node1`

and `/etc/resolv.conf` contains:

```
 nameserver 8.8.8.8
 search localdomain
```

The `/etc/nsswitch.conf` also specifies the order `hosts: files dns`.

The Hadoop namenode is set to `hdfs://node1:9000`

Now when I run `hadoop namenode`, it hangs for about 5-10 seconds. Further investigation using `tcpdump` shows that Hadoop is trying to resolve the namenode via `8.8.8.8`, and due to my network settings it is very slow.

When I comment out the `nameserver 8.8.8.8`, the same command runs in less than 1 second, because it seems to pickup the resolution for `node1` directly from `/etc/hosts`.

So is this the case that ***name resolution in Java, or at least in Hadoop, always resolves DNS first and only when failed does it use `/etc/hosts`***? I've been trying to search for similar experience, but to no avail.

Comment: you could setup a local, caching only bind server which would allow you to resolve and cache the name locally, but still be able to get other DNS resolutions when needed...using this method, you could even go so far as to setup a local `.hadoop` domain so all of your nodes were available when you start scaling out

Comment: thanks. Actually I could point to another local gateway that are quicker at responding. My question was whether it is true that Java ignores /etc/hosts when resolving host name.

Comment: I'm not a Java developer, but have supported many Java based applications both on weblogic and tomcat and, unless you're actually building a connection to fetch the records, Java should be handing the resolution request to the local system which should honor the system's settings.